# To have ISBN field in Biblatex for Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib

I want to have ISBN field in my Bibtex.
I learned from Andrew that it is best done with Biblatex as a whole.
So I want to move from Natbib to Biblatex.

I am getting this error to Andrew's code, when I have the file *article.bib* in the folder:

[image]

**How can you show ISBN field of articles and books in Bibliography?**

So mainly

```
./article.tex:2: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

I have used Typesetting engines XeLaTeX and Pdflatex, but get the same errors.

Comment: Are you intending to use `natbib` (as package loading suggests) or `biblatex` (as options suggest)?

Comment: I can use biblatex. I am trying to do so. Please, see my error messages in the comment to Andrew.

Comment: Please make sure edits keep the question understandable: at the moment a new reader would not really follow what is going on!

Comment: @JosephWright I wrote there now an explanation what is going on.

Comment: "Missing `\begin{document}` in general means that there is something printable in the preamble. In case your tex-file is utf8 encoded this can be something invisible like a non-breakable space or a unicode BOM at the begin of the tex-document. In your case you are getting the error because you are not loading biblatex, so `\addbibresource` is not defined and the text after the command is not seen as argument but as normal text.

Comment: I doubt that the problem is that one. See Doed's comment below. I believe that the problem is in the newest version of the program. My data https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/article.zip which does not work in my system.

Comment: Doed's example works without problem for me. Your tex file is faulty, you are using `\listfiles` after `\begin{document}` despite the error message which clearly tells you that this isn't allowed. Learn to read the log-file. It is there to help you to correct errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Run the code without "listfiles" in the newest program, you get the same errors as I listed above. The problem is in the version.

Comment: When I run the code without listfiles I get an empty document as it has not content. If I additionally uncomment the addbibresource line I get your error as -- as I already told you -- you don't load biblatex in your document. You need a `\usepackage{biblatex}` line before `\addbibresource`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right. I updated the code. I need to be in the document class **revtex4-1** because I need two-column mode. Is Biblatex possible with revtex? I updated the error code.

Comment: No revtex4-1 will not work with biblatex, not without some amount of hacking. But twocolumn mode can be use with almost every class. I suggest that you read some introduction to latex.

Comment: @Masi how many .bib files do you have? The reason I'm asking is because I know that you have used the `jobname.bib` before, haven't you? The same goes for `article.bib` Either way you do it, make sure is the only file with a unique name, in the same folder (as you know), but most importantly run BibTeX

Comment: @doed I have only one. The name is only Andrew's example. I use article name in my case. I use Texpad in OSX which runs Bibtex for me. The **problem is at the moment that I cannot run biblatex in the document class revtex4-1** for some reason, see my updated post.

Comment: @Masi right. So what are the options? About a week ago if memory serves me right, someone recommended the option `lpr` for the two columns in revtex, so either use `natbib` or `makebst` with the customized features you want in the bibliography

Comment: @doed **Do you mean that Biblatex with ISBN support and twocolumn mode is impossible by standard packages?** I do not like to hack things. I would like to fullfill requirements for my publication: twocolumn mode and ISBN/DOI in the bibliography.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be loading the `biblatex` package with the `natbib` option, not the `natbib` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex, 
    natbib=true, 
    bibstyle=verbose, citestyle=verbose,    % bibstyle extensively modifed below
    doi=true, url=true,                     % excluded from citations below
    citecounter=true, citetracker=true,
    block=space, 
    backref=true, backrefstyle=two,
    abbreviate=false,
    isbn=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where the `bib` file contains:

```
@Book{Armstrong:symmetry,
  author =   {Armstrong, M. A.},
  title =    {Groups and symmetry},
  series =   {Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics},
  publisher =    {Springer-Verlag},
  address =  {New York},
  year =     1988,
  pages =    {xii+186},
  isbn =     {0-387-96675-7}
}
```

Also, in a user level document the correct command is `\usepackage` not `\RequirePackage`

On the other hand, if you were really intending to use the `natbib` package, then the syntax would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: second sample]

with isbn included by default.

Comment: I cannot understand the errors that I get when I run your first example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-30%20at%2022.25.29.png and mainly *./article.tex:2: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.*

Comment: @Masi Sounds like a version issue: add `\listfiles` to your input and report the resulting `File list` (in the `.log` file) in the question.

Comment: @JosephWright Or this way? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-30%20at%2023.53.11.png

Comment: I got a bunch of errors with the above. Errors that normally would not be there in the first place. I am wondering now about the latest biblatex update??

Comment: You need to replace `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` with the actually bibliography file you are using.  Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Andrew. Among the errors I was getting with the same code than in your answer `Database file #1: questionaboutbiblatex5-blx.bib
Biblatex version: 2.7
(There was 1 error message)

BibTeX exited abnormally with code 2 at Thu Oct 31 13:54:57`

Comment: The error in your dropbox file is having `\addbibresource` before loading the package `biblatex`, the command is not known at that point.

Comment: The natbib (second suggestion) doesn't print ISBNs using RevTeX. I'll try further things.